# mongodb driver - how to hide debug logging with log4j?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, logging, log4j

Mongo java driver is verbose since v3.x.x, it's not very optimal to store a log of logs like this. Would like to hide some of them.

Here are my dependencies (maven / pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- LOGS -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>    
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

I want to hide mongo java driver logs :

```
2015-05-16 10:43:22 023 DEBUG command:56 - Sending command {count : BsonString{value='skydatas'}} to database rizze on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:9}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
2015-05-16 10:43:22 041 DEBUG command:56 - Command execution completed
2015-05-16 10:43:22 042 DEBUG command:56 - Sending command {count : BsonString{value='skydatas'}} to database rizze on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:9}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
2015-05-16 10:43:22 060 DEBUG command:56 - Command execution completed


2015-05-16T10:49:34.448Z DEBUG Checking status of 127.0.0.1:27017 |   | cluster:56
2015-05-16T10:49:34.452Z DEBUG Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=1,3 ms, state=CONNECTED}] |   | cluster:56
```

Thanks

Comment: I've same issue. I'm investigating.

Comment: andrea please take a look to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this from your log4j configuration file.

The first thing I would do is temporarily add the fully-qualified class name to your log4j appender format (`%C` if you're using a formatter based on [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)). That gives you the package and class names of the source of the logging statements you want to exclude.

Then follow the example from the [log4j manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) to specifically raise the logging level of the packages/classes you don't want to see (search the page for text from the snippet below to find it on the page for more context):

```
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

Don't forget to take the `%C` out of your pattern when you've excluded all the packages you don't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a log4j configuration, I'm using with log4j:

```
# Log4J logger file
log = ./log4j
log4j.rootLogger = WARN, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.com.rizze.db=INFO


# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS} %-5p %m / %c{1}:%L %n
```

What is doing this work around
- show Logs with level >= INFO for package com.rizze.db
- show others Logs with level >= WARN

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me.

add this line to you log4j configuration to fix this problem.

`log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver=ERROR`